I was upgrading and I logged out, now I am unable to login
This is my first post so if I do something wrong I would appreciate it if you correct me so I am able to resolve the issues for future posts.
I was in the middle of an upgrade when I accidentally logged out. Now when I try to log back in it gives me the "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." message telling me "...the system can't recover."

I tried logging into the console via recovery mode but it tels me "Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked."

I am unable to type any commands, all I am able to do is press enter. When I do that I notice some messages stating system files are messed up and it is placing new files in for compatibility purposes. It goes by pretty quickly so I am unable to get a picture or even read exactly what it says.
I also tried the trick where you edit the recovery mode option within the Grub menu to allow you to gain access by giving you root access without the need of a password but that didn't do anything.
Thanks in advance for any help, it will be very much appreciated!
***Edit:
First of all, thank you all for answering my post and trying to give some guidance! The thing is that I used to use Kali as my daily driver so I had built up pictures and other person items that I've comed to treasure, however, it was only after seeing the post by @Marcus-Müller that it dawned on me!
You see I tripple boot Windows 11, Ubuntu 24.04, and Kali Linux so I was able to get into my Kali partition and copy everything from my home folder. I'm doing this now and will create a live usb and reinstall my Kali OS.
Once again I'd really like to thank everyone of you for not chastising me and giving me real-world solutions!
~Ryan

For Kali I'd suggest you simply reinstall from scratch. It's not as if it's a daily driver where you'd want to keep your data

@ChrisDavies Reinstallation is very seldom an appropriate solution here, even when the system in question is Kali Linux.

@Kusalananda for a broken upgrade the cost effectiveness of reinstalling is likely better than trying to boot an installation/rescue disk and picking up the pieces. IMO, of course

@ChrisDavies That's a different (and better) reason than "you're running Kali, just reinstall" as you had in your first comment.

I would differentiate between a daily driver with valuable data and any installation otherwise. Nevertheless if you strongly disagree with me you are welcome to delete the comments and I'll walk away, @Kusalananda

@ChrisDavies Neither of us knows what the system's content holds or what its value is to the user.  If it's worthless, a reinstallation may be the best option.  I'm just hesitant to come to that conclusion solely on the basis of the name of the distribution.

Hi Ryan! Welcome here! As you might have noticed above, this would be a natural point where you might choose to just boot from a live medium, make a copy of your home directory, and just start from scratch rather than save your system. Which would probably be relatively little pain if your data and customizations mostly concerned your own user and things you can do via apt.

@Kusalananda ChrisDavies I think this is a consensus form of "hey, it looks like you're using Kali, which you probably shouldn't do as a daily driver, but if you feel you have good reason to resuscitate this system, be aware that a fresh setup is an option that might be easier"
